# Kivy error Camera Webcam gives error VideoCapture:Resolution not found

Tags: python, video, camera, kivy, webcam

I have a Kivy App and I am trying to take a video from my webcam camera to put it in my application on my computer. I got this code online which was :-

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
'''


class TestCamera(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TestCamera().run()
```

I am getting an error stating that VideoCapture:Resolution Not Found in kivy/core/camera/camera_videocaputure. I tied to figure out many different ways yet I could not resolve the query. It would be great if anyone could help me out with it. Thanks !

The error Traceback is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\BinaryHeap.py", line 23, in     <module>
     TestCamera().run()


   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\BinaryHeap.py", line 21, in build
     return Builder.load_string(kv)
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1921, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 2130, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 6:
 ...
       4:    Camera:
       5:        id: camera
 >>    6:        resolution: (640, 480)
       7:        play: False
       8:    ToggleButton:
 ...
 Exception: VideoCapture: Resolution not supported
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 2123, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 22, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__ (kivy\weakproxy.c:1235)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 408, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy\properties.c:5114)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 733, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set (kivy\properties.c:11127)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 446, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:5876)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 501, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy\properties.c:6557)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1224, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:13497)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1130, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12696)
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
     resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_videocapture.py", line 26, in __init__
     super(CameraVideoCapture, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
     self.init_camera()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\personal work\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_videocapture.py", line 36, in init_camera
     raise Exception('VideoCapture: Resolution not supported')
```

[-1,-1] also does not work just provides me with a blank screen. If someone tries it please temme if it worked for them ? Is there any other way I can get the camera working ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera 

class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        return self.my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        self.capture.release()


CamApp().run()
```

The above code works for me but I don't know how to change it to a kivy file. So I would appreciate any help. Thanks. I took a picture and my camera resolution was 1920 x 1080. I just thought it might help.

Comment: Thanks for the editing !

Comment: Can you add the complete error/traceback?

Comment: What happens if you delete the resolution line?

Comment: If I remove the resolution line it does not show the image/video at all but doesn't give the error as well !

Comment: I cannot put the picture of the error due to low reputation but the complete error is what I stated in the question

Comment: Pictures of errors are always bad, pasting the error is much better. There should be more information than that single line, a normal error beginning with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and ending with `TypeError: Object is not callable` or whatever the detailed information is.

Comment: I have made the edit with the complete error message. BinaryHeap is the file name

Comment: The chosen resolution is not supported by your camera. You should be able to use `[-1, -1]` which then uses the camera default.

Comment: I made the edit but it is still giving me a blank screen ! Is there anything else I can do ?

Comment: What exactly is the blank screen? Did you hit the "play" button? The camera will not record if you don't do anything. You can try with `play: True`, that should have the same effect as pressing the button.

Comment: yes I tried by hitting the play button as well as doing play:True. It doesnot work ! :(. Could you check if it works for you maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment so I'll leave it here.
Both your scripts are working fine on my laptop. I've tried several resolutions and all of them are supported: 1920x1080, 640x480, 320x240.
Check your kivy and OpenCV versions. Mine is:
OpenCV 2.4.12
Kivy v1.9.0
Python v2.7.8

Comment: I am gonna surely try it and if not I will install the different versions. Could you also tell me what OS you are running on. I am using a 64 bit Windows 10. I hope that's not causing a problem.Also could you tell me which computer you are using ? I might be able to check out the specifications for the camera

Comment: I'm running on 64 bit Windows 7 and actually OS should not cause such a problem.

Comment: Hi I have added the same versions but it still gives me an error. I feel that there is a problem with my kivy file video_capture because it keeps giving me an error. I have tried using an external camera as well. Is there anyway I can solve the problem ?

Comment: It seems you're using Kivy from Anaconda platform. Try installing just Kivy and OpenCV packages (with dependencies) in a fresh environment via `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I ran the program on Windows 7 and it works ! I am not sure if it was an OS problem or not but it is working. So if someone makes it working for Windows 8 or 10 please comment. I wasted a lot of time debugging this and could not get it working on those 2 OS. Well anyway thankfully got it working and thank you dizcza for your reply.It was really helpful. I did upvote you but it does not show up due to my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

pip install opencv-python

from here: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ fixed it for me.

Windows 10, Python 3.6, Kivy 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

if you are using anaconda spyder application to run this script then that is the real reason you are getting that error (i had the same error).  Try using another editor with kivy package installed (try Pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def test_camera_resolutions(self, source, size):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(source) 
    w, h = size

    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, h)

    if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
        print('Camera do not effort this resolutions!')
```